# speech recognizer set text in edit text mishap (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-edittext, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am using the speech to text concept using speech recognizer, but when the text is set to the edit text, the existing text in the edit text is erased and the text converted from the speech is set in its place. [image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]
But, I want the converted text to be set after the existing text, without replacing the existing text.

```
public class AddNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int RECORDAUDIOREQUESTCODE = 1;
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
ImageView micButton;

public static final String EXTRA_ID = "EXTRA_ID";

public static final String EXTRA_TITLE =
        "EXTRA_TITLE";
public static final String EXTRA_DESCRIPTION =
        "EXTRA_DESCRIPTION";
private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextDescription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)!=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        checkPermission();
    }
    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
    editTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_description);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_baseline_close_24);
    micButton = findViewById(R.id.mic);
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            editTextDescription.setSelection(editTextDescription.getText().length());
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            editTextDescription.setSelection(editTextDescription.getText().length());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            micButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_off_24);
            ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            editTextDescription.setSelection(editTextDescription.getText().length());
            editTextDescription.setText(data.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }
    });
    micButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            micButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24);
            speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
        }
    }); 
 @Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    speechRecognizer.destroy();
}
private void checkPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                RECORDAUDIOREQUESTCODE);
    }
}
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    if(requestCode==RECORDAUDIOREQUESTCODE && grantResults.length>0){
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    micButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_off_24);
    ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    editTextDescription.setSelection(editTextDescription.getText().length());
    editTextDescription.setText(data.get(0));
}
```

You're telling it to hilight the entire text, then you set the text.  That's going to get rid of whatever the selection is (it's also redundant, as the same thing would happen if you didn't set the selection).  If you want to continue it, use

```
editTextDescription.setText(editTextDescription.getText().toString()+data.get(0))
```

That should replace the last 2 lines of that function.  It will get the existing text, tack the new result to it, and set the total string to the view.